# How to read and write to a .txt file located on a s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a challenge that asks me to update the number inside a .txt file with the next prime number. The problem is that it must be updated inside an s3 bucket, and I really don't know how to read/write inside a file in s3 using nodeJS. I'm using a Lambda function to do it.

I tried to search inside AWS SDK S3 documentation to get some input but didn't have success. I'm new to cloud so I'm struggling to understand some 
concepts.

I used fs to read/write to a local file:

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var calculateNextPrime = function (currentNumber) {
    var divisor = 0;
    var isTrue = false;
    currentNumber++;

    while (isTrue === false) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= currentNumber; i++) {
            if (currentNumber % i === 0) {
                divisor++;   
            }
        }
        if (divisor === 2) {
            isTrue = true;
        } else {
            currentNumber += 1;
            divisor = 0;

        }
    }
    return currentNumber;
}


var fileContent = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
fileContent = Number(fileContent);

var newFileContent = insertNextPrime(fileContent);
fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', newFileContent);
```

Comment: A few minor comments that I think would improve your code: prefer `let/const` to `var`, use `if (x)` or `if (!x)` rather than comparing booleans with true or false, the `isTrue` variable name doesn't convey any useful meaning, use `break` instead of introducing a new boolean simply to get out of a loop, your `calculateNextPrime()` method is not optimal but presumably works OK.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update S3 objects in place. You must replace the entire object. To do that, use [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property).

Answer (score 1):

try this for write to txt file

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    string = "Hello world"
    encoded_string = string.encode("utf-8")

    bucket_name = "s3bucketName"
    file_name = "abc.txt"
    lambda_path = "/tmp/" + file_name
    s3_path = "pathToFileName/" + file_name

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=encoded_string)
```

for reading data from txt u can use this

```
with open(filename) as f:
    string = f.read()

encoded_string = string.encode("utf-8")
print(encoded_string )
```